# Extract expected data from http client getAsync

Tags: c#, get, asp.net-web-api

I want to get the exact data being return from my web api. Now I can extract the request. But I'm not sure if it is correct. Because in my web api it should return nothing if the ID I send it not found. But If I check the content, there's a value. So I think extracting request from the response is not just it. There should be more.

Here's my code.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiUserName", "maddio1003api");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiToken", "1fe1a0a9555afc85fa87f03b2c4439fdd5a840cc");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiOwner", "maddios");

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://162.220.58.122:5008/1.0/Customers?$filter=(" + userId + "%20eq%201234)&$expand=Transactions").;  // Blocking call!
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = response.Content; //I think this is not what I need to look on if I want to see the actual data I want to see.
            returnBool = true;
        }
        else
        {
            returnBool = false;
        }
```

I'm using getAsync because I based this on what I saw in some tutorials. But if you have a better way of doing a get request suggestions will be fully appreciated.

I am expecting a JSON data and what I see in the content are other properties like headers and stuff I don't need. Just the JSON data. How do I extract it?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Well what's the value you're seeing in Content? It's unclear whether you're really concerned with client behaviour or finding a bug in the web API...

Comment: Shouldn't you be `await`ing `GetAsync`?

Comment: I just want to get the returned value from my web API. That's it.

Comment: I just saw this while researching. If there's a better way to make a GET request. Please do suggest.

Comment: I'm expecting a json data by the way.

Comment: @ljpv14 Could you edit your post to show what data you're expecting versus what data you're getting?

Comment: as @DanielMann pointed out, how is this even compiling? You should be getting a compiler error on `HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("...");`; It needs to be `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("...");`

Comment: I'm now getting any compiler error.